# How can we print the visited URL to error_log

Tags: xdebug, xdebug-3, xdebug-profiler

We would like the error-log to include the URL (uri) of the original page called by the visitor.

A user visits a web page (URL).
The page is generated by multiple PHP scripts
One of the scripts triggers an error

In the logs, I see the script name that triggered the error.
But I cannot see what URL the visitor visited to trigger this whole thing.

How can we set this up?

Comment: Can you add a bit more context? I don't understand what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added more info to the question. Hoping this is clearer.